# Refresh Enhancedgrid with dojo.data.ObjectStore

Tags: javascript, dojo, dojox.grid

I'm using 1.7.2
When I add an item to objectstore I write

```
dataStore.newItem(data);
```

Then I tried saving `dataStore.save()` and then `dijit.byId(gridId)._refresh()`
But browser hangs up.

I also tried re-assigning same store again to grid after adding item. Still no success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling

```
        dijit.byId(gridId).resize()
```

Comment: @RaviKhakhkhar You are trying to add data to Grid. After addition its not viewable or your browser is freezing

Comment: Honestly, When I was trying day before yesterday, browser was freezing due to store.save(), but now using store.save() not causing that(I don't know reason). At the moment newly added item is not visible.

Comment: have you set the overflow style to auto?

Comment: sorry. It's done. It was my big fault. Forgot to set handleAs:json and because of that it was not coming in grid. Your soluction is working. upvoted :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the grid's setQuery method.

```
dijit.byId(gridId).setQuery(query);
```

Comment: sorry Richard. Your point was right. By doing this we can actually refresh grid. At that point I was not using query and so was not convinced by your idea.